# Kohana 3.2 - Database search returns empty object

Tags: php, mysql, search, kohana, limit

Try to make 'archive' for my blog. If the search run for unavaliable items the return is an empty object. Here is my code:

**For example wrong input:**

http://www.my-site.com/archive/2011/01/27 - in database no post with this date 2011-01-27

The controller action:

```
public function action_archive() {
    $posts_model = new Model_Posts();

    // Év pl.: 2012
    if($year = $this->request->param("year")) {
        // Hónap pl.: 2012-03
        if($month = $this->request->param("month")) {
            // Nap pl.: 2012-03-27
            if($day = $this->request->param("day")) {
                if ($posts = $posts_model->get_post_by_date($year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day)) {
                    $this->template->content = View::factory('posts/default')
                        ->bind('posts', $posts);
                } else
                    throw new HTTP_Exception_404;
            } else {
                if($posts = $posts_model->get_post_by_date($year . "-" . $month)) {
                    $this->template->content = View::factory('posts/default')
                        ->bind('posts', $posts);
                } else
                    throw new HTTP_Exception_404;
            }

        } else {
            if($posts = $posts_model->get_post_by_date($year)) {
                $this->template->content = View::factory('posts/default')
                    ->bind('posts', $posts);
            } else
                throw new HTTP_Exception_404;
        }
    } else
        // Nem található archívum
        throw new HTTP_Exception_404;

    return false;
}
```

I am try to throw 404 exception if the search fails. Here comes the model:

```
public function get_post_by_date($date) {
    try {
        return DB::select()
            ->from("posts")
            ->where("date", "like", "$date%")
            ->and_where("publish", "=", "1")
            ->as_object()
            ->execute();
    } catch (Database_Exception $e) {
        Kohana::$log->add(Log::ERROR, Database_Exception::text($e));
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Edit your question please to specify

Comment: Try turning on the profiler and seeing what the SQL is that it's running.

Comment: It would be even nicer, if post actually contained a question ...

Comment: My problem is, the return is an empty object, with the wrong input. With good indput, it works perfectly.

Comment: why are you expecting database exception? 0 records result does not mean database exeption

Comment: Ok. I googled a lot. My problem now is, the query string is good. But the return is true with 0 size object. I forgot this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to check if there is a particular entry in the database use
    ->execute()->count();

In your case you will need the actual posts, so you can use the count method of the Database_Result class (it implements the Countable interface).

```
$posts = $posts_model->get_post_by_date($year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day);
if ($posts->count()) {
    $this->template->content = View::factory('posts/default')
        ->bind('posts', $posts);
} else
    throw new HTTP_Exception_404;
```

And remove that try-catch block. You don't need it if your query is correct.